# Check query result with two column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Here is the table structure.

```
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  + No + UniqueID + Email             + Status +
  + 1  + 1q2w3e4r + myemail@gmail.com + NULL   +
  + 2  + 12345qwe + myemail@yahoo.com + 1      +
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

The logic should be:

1. I want to input `UniqueID` and `Email`. When I put the value is `1q2w3e4r` and `Email` `myemai@gmail.com`, it shoudl return True or put the uniqueID as response like this one below:
   $this->response(array('2' => $data['UniqueID']));
2. Same No.1 but it should return false, because i put `UniqueID` that already has `status = 1`.
3. Same As No.1 and 2, but this time i put the wrong `uniqueID`. eg. uniqueID is 1234567. it shoud return false because uniqueID is not true.

And my code looks like this below:

=========================================================================
Solve The Problem by modify this code below:

Model

```
  public function signup($data)
  {
    $this->db->select("status");
    $this->db->from("mytable");
    $this->db->where("UniqueID ", $data['UniqueID ']);
    $this->db->where("email", $data['email']);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q;
  }
```

and my controller like this below:

```
if($result->num_rows() > 0) {
  $s = $result->row()->status;
  if (isset($s) && $s == 1)
  {
    $this->response(array('1' => 'missing data'));
  } else if(!isset($s)){
    $this->response(array('2' => $data['nopolis']));
  }
} else {
  $this->response(array('3' => 'missing'));
}
```

Comment: As my understanding from your question itself you have answer.
Check the if case how you are expected using &&

Comment: i already did, but what if i put the wrong value of the uniqueID. you check my code above @jagadeesh

Comment: Provide the structure of your table.

Comment: Im confused. You say this: _"how do I make No.1 false so it returns missing user or wrong data ?"_  which by No.1 I belive you mean this: _if UniqueID = true and status = 1_ . What I dont understand is why would this be false if you actually do have a valid result??

Comment: If your uniqueID is not present then the query returns empty right.?

Comment: yeah right if the uniqueID is not present or miss type it will return empty @jagadeesh

Answer (score 1):

Kind of hard to understand you. But I believe you are looking for something like this. Try the following:

First, change your model method to this:

```
public function signup($data){
    $this->db->select("status");
    $this->db->from("mytable");
    $this->db->where("uniqueID", $data['uniqueID ']);
    $this->db->where("email", $data['email']);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q->row();
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
public function validation_post(){
    $data = array (
        'uniqueID' => $this->input->get_post('nopolis')
    );

    $result = $this->signup->signup($data);
    $s = $result->status;
    if ($result) {
        $s = $result->status;
        if (isset($s) && $s == 1) {
            //Condition where status = 1
        } else if (!isset($s)) {
            //Condition where status = NULL
        } else {
            //Condition where status is something else
        }
    } else {
        //Condition where id and email does not exist
        echo "No Results";
    }
}
```

Comment: :-P sorry. i alread try ur code but it seem something error with the model. this the error i found. SELECT status
FROM mytable, status
WHERE uniqueID= '12345qwerty'
AND email = 'myemail@email.com'

but when i tried remove get('status') the model worked @codegodie

Comment: no.1 and no.2 worked, but no.3 not work. the result is in my thread @codegodie

Comment: ok. I think it would be best if you edited your OP(Original Post), and include the structure of your table. This way I can come up with an efficient piece of code.